# Increment integer in set range

Tags: php, arrays

If I want to loop through an array and then use them as looped increment counters, how would I do that?

E.g. I have up to 5 values stored in an array. I want to loop through them, and in the forst loop I want to use a specific value, then for the second another specific value.

Pseudo code below, but how do I bring in the second array into the picture? The first range is going to dynamic and empty or have up to 5 values. The second will be fixed.

```
$array = array(2,6,8); // Dynamic

$array2 = array(11,45,67,83,99); Fixed 5 values

foreach ($array as $value) {
    // First loop, insert or use both 2 and 11 together
    // Second loop, insert or use both 6 and 45
    // Third loop, insert or use both 8 and 67
}
```

Comment: You meant 2 and 11 togheter?

Comment: `foreach($array as $key=>$value)`. Then `$array2[$key]`

Comment: Yep - that's right - typo, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$index => $val`:

```
foreach ($array2 as $index => $value) {
    if ( isset($array[ $index ]) ) {
          echo $array[ $index ]; // 2, then 6, then 8
    }
    echo $value; // 11, then 45, then 67, then 83, then 99 
}
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/gpPmUG

---

If you want it to stop once you're at the end of the first array, then loop through the first array:

```
foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
    echo $value; // 2, then 6, then 8
    echo $array2[ $index ]; // 11, then 45, then 67
}
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/578zfQ

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clean and simple solution, that does not uses useless and heavy non standard libraries:

```
$a = count($array);
$b = count($array2);
$x = ($a > $b) ? $b : $a;
for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
    $array[$i]; // this will be 2 the first iteration, then 6, then 8.
    $array2[$i]; // this will be 11 the first iteration, then 45, then 67.
}
```

We just use `$i` to identify the same position of the two arrays inside the main `for` loop in order to use them together. The main `for` loop will iterate the correct number of times so that none of the two arrays will use undefined indexes (causing notices errors).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

```
foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
      echo $array[ $index ]; // 2, then 6, then 8
      echo $array2[ $index ]; // 11, then 45, then 67

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Determine the minimum length of both arrays.

Then loop your index `i` from 1 to the minimum length.

Now you can use the `i`-th element of both arrays

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you want:

```
foreach($array as $value){
     for($x = $value; $array[$value]; $x++){
       //Do something here...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [MultipleIterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/multipleiterator.construct.php):

```
$arrays = new MultipleIterator(
    MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY|MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_NUMERIC
);
$arrays->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator([2,6,8]));
$arrays->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator([11,45,67,83,99]));

foreach ($arrays as $value) {
    print_r($value);
}
```

will print:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 11 ) 
Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 45 ) 
Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 67 ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => 83 ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => 99 )
```

If you want it to require both arrays to have a value, change the flags to

```
MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL|MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_NUMERIC
```

which will then give

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 11 ) 
Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 45 ) 
Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 67 )
```